# ORACLE SQL select distinct not removing duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle, select, distinct

I have the following tables; format: table_name[column1, column2, etc..]

```
VENDOR_ORDERS [ORDER_ID, ORDER_CREATION_DATETIME, REGION_ID, ZIP_CODE, AMOUNT]
CALENDAR [CALENDAR_WEEK, CALENDAR_DATE]
```

basically what i'm trying to achieve is writing a query that will give me:

the `COUNT(ORDER_ID)` and `SUM(AMOUNT)` per `CALENDAR_WEEK` for every `REGION_ID` and `DISTINCT(ZIP_CODE)`

so the results should look something like this:

```
ZIP_CODE    CALENDAR_WEEK    REGION_ID    COUNT(ORDER_ID)    SUM(AMOUNT)
                            --------------------
XXXXX           01              1             50               987.45
YYYYY           01              1             25               568.32
ZZZZZ           01              1             30               555.63
MMMMM           01              1             10               099.93
XXXXX           15              1             05               999.34
YYYYY           15              1             32               339.67
ZZZZZ           15              1             21               457.23
MMMMM           15              1             88               459.99
```

i used the following code:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT(vo.ZIP_CODE)
    ,TO_CHAR(ca.CALENDAR_WEEK)
    ,TRUNC(vo.ORDER_CREATION_DATETIME) -- this column is not needed, i just added it for visualization purposes
    ,vo.REGION_ID
    ,COUNT(vo.ORDER_ID)
    ,SUM(vo.AMOUNT)
FROM
    VENDOR_ORDERS vo
    ,CALENDAR ca
WHERE   
    TRUNC(vo.ORDER_CREATION_DATETIME) = sd.CALENDAR_DATE
    AND vo.REGION_ID = 1
GROUP BY
    vo.ZIP_CODE
    ,TO_CHAR(ca.CALENDAR_WEEK)
    ,vo.ORDER_CREATION_DATETIME
    ,vc.REGION_ID;
```

the problem is that i'm not getting `DISTINCT(ZIP_CODE)` per `CALENDAR_WEEK`, i'm having repeated `ZIP_CODE` for the same `CALENDAR_WEEK`, same `REGION_ID` but different `COUNT(ORDER_ID)` and `SUM(AMOUNT)`

i hope i made myself clear.
thanks in advance for the help

Comment: `distinct` is ***NOT*** a function. It is always applied for **all** columns in the select list.

Comment: You cannot group by date column and expect the results to be grouped by a week! remove it from the group by and either remove it from the select or select it with min or max

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You misunderstand what `distinct` is.  It is not a function.  It is a modifier on `select` and it affects *all* columns being selected.  So, it is behaving exactly as it should.

If you want aggregations by zip code and week, then those are the only two columns that should be in the `group by`:

```
SELECT vo.ZIP_CODE, TO_CHAR(ca.CALENDAR_WEEK),
       -- vo.REGION_ID
        COUNT(vo.ORDER_ID),
        SUM(vo.AMOUNT)
FROM VENDOR_ORDERS vo JOIN
     CALENDAR ca
     ON TRUNC(vo.ORDER_CREATION_DATETIME) = sd.CALENDAR_DATE
WHERE vo.REGION_ID = 1
GROUP BY vo.ZIP_CODE, TO_CHAR(ca.CALENDAR_WEEK)
```

You could probably include `region_id` as well, assuming that each zip code is in one region.

Comment: one last question, i followed your advice but kept the DISTINCT and it seems i got exactly what i wanted. i see you removed it in your suggestion, is there much of a difference?

Comment: There is almost never a need to use `select distinct` with a `group by` query.  In the very *rare* circumstance that you need it, you'll understand SQL well-enough to use it.  So, don't include it because it is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Your DISTINCT has no purpose in this query it will be applied to all columns  and not to ORDER_ID only as you think. Think about this: if you have several ORDER_ID with different values for all other columns, how Oracle would know which one to return ??

Additionnaly it is useless  to specify the DISTINCT because you are doing a GROUP BY which finally achieve the same results.

And last but not least, you're wrong when you say this in your comments:

```
-- this column is not needed, i just added it for visualization
```

You need it in your SELECT because it is an essential field of your GROUP BY

Without seing data sample I can't say it 100%, but your issue is probably due to the fact that in your select you make a TRUNC on your datetime field, and not in your GROUP BY clause. So it doesn't return what you want and you don't understand why because your select show you a truncated date, you think that the GROUP BY worked also on date, but its not the case, it  grouped on **DATE and TIME**

To understand your issue, do:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT(vo.ZIP_CODE)
    ,TO_CHAR(ca.CALENDAR_WEEK)
    ,vo.ORDER_CREATION_DATETIME 
    ,vo.REGION_ID
    ,COUNT(vo.ORDER_ID)
    ,SUM(vo.AMOUNT)
FROM
    VENDOR_ORDERS vo
    ,CALENDAR ca
WHERE   
    TRUNC(vo.ORDER_CREATION_DATETIME) = sd.CALENDAR_DATE
    AND vo.REGION_ID = 1
GROUP BY
    vo.ZIP_CODE
    ,TO_CHAR(ca.CALENDAR_WEEK)
    ,vo.ORDER_CREATION_DATETIME
    ,vc.REGION_ID;
```

To fix your issue, do:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT(vo.ZIP_CODE)
    ,TO_CHAR(ca.CALENDAR_WEEK)
    ,TRUNC(vo.ORDER_CREATION_DATETIME) 
    ,vo.REGION_ID
    ,COUNT(vo.ORDER_ID)
    ,SUM(vo.AMOUNT)
FROM
    VENDOR_ORDERS vo
    ,CALENDAR ca
WHERE   
    TRUNC(vo.ORDER_CREATION_DATETIME) = sd.CALENDAR_DATE
    AND vo.REGION_ID = 1
GROUP BY
    vo.ZIP_CODE
    ,TO_CHAR(ca.CALENDAR_WEEK)
    ,TRUNC(vo.ORDER_CREATION_DATETIME)
    ,vc.REGION_ID;
```